# Attach JSON to file upload

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-file-upload

I'm implementing a file-uploading service using [blueimp's jQuery-File-Upload](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload) plugin.

I need to attach an authentication-token to each post.
How can this be achieved?

My code (simplified a bit):

HTML:

```
<div class="dropzone">
  <input style="display:none;" id="fileupload" type="file" name="file" data-url="http://192.168.99.100/api/classify" multiple>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
var auth_token = {"auth_token": "blablablabla"};
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#fileupload').fileupload({
  dropZone: $(".dropzone")});
});
```

Comment: https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/How-to-submit-additional-form-data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`formData`](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/API#data-attributes) @ api:

```
var auth_token = {"auth_token": "blablablabla"};
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#fileupload').fileupload({
    dropZone: $(".dropzone"),
    formData : auth_token
  });
});
```